# Getting currently logged in user with multiple login systems

Tags: laravel

I have created two login systems, one for users and one for admins.  Both are working.  I am now trying to get the currently logged in admin.

I have the following route:

```
Route::resource ('general-contact-us-submissions', 'internal_admin\GeneralContactUsSubmissionsController');
```

I have the following in my controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    //
    $user = Auth::admin()->id;
    // $user = auth()->admin();
    dd($user);
}
```

I have the following in my Admin model:

```
protected $guard = 'admin';
```

When I dd($user), I get the following:

Method Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::admin does not exist.

Comment: because its `Auth::guard('admin')....` where did you see `Auth::admin()`? and where did you see this reference about setting `$guard` on the model?

Comment: Got it.  I didn't realize the guard had to be inserted.  The dd works now if I do $user = Auth::guard('admin') but I still can't get the admins id with $user = Auth::guard('admin')->id;.  It says Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::$id

Comment: because that is the guard not the user, it would be `Auth::guard('admin')->id()` or `Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id` ... where did you see it with just `guard()->id`?  like honestly, what is the reference you are using to come up with this? i've seen people try to use these before and I dont know why but would like to know why

Comment: i misinterpreted something.  i saw thecorrect way to use the Auth facade with the built-in user model (Auth::user....).  I thought I could simply plug in 'admin' for 'user'

Comment: ah okay, no worries .. i have seen people try to use that exact method numerous times and other things, figured there was some mulit-auth library from the past that used them ... good luck with your project :)